# El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, system.io

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual está iterando siempre y cuando exite un archivo, que está valido en la variable existePagoPos, despues de leerlo, lo elimina:

```
       String contenido_pago;
        while (true)
            {
                bool existePagoPos = File.Exists(path_pagos_pos);

                if (existePagoPos)
                {
                    //contenido_pago = File.ReadAllText(path_pagos_pos);
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path_pagos_pos, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        contenido_pago = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    
                    File.Delete(path_pagos_pos);
                }
            }
```

La primera vez lo lee bien y lo elimina, pero cuando copio nuevamente el mismo archivo (que tiene el mismo nombre) da el siguiente error:

**el proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso**

Se cae en la linea  **contenido_pago = streamReader.ReadToEnd();**

Alguien sabe porque pasa esto, si el archivo ya se eliminó y esta tratando de leer otro, pero que tiene el mismo nombre, como podría solucionarlo?

Al probar de esta forma, sale el mismo error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Donde declaras contenido_pago, y de que tipo es

Comment: ahí la edite, es un String

Comment: Quizá se necesite un poco de tiempo para liberar los recursos utilizados por el objeto StreamReader, usando tu código inicial podrías agregar Thread.Sleep(100); antes de eliminar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione colocando Thread.Sleep(300); cuando pregunta si existe el archivo, con las idea de @Jefferson Cuji pude resolverlo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta primero cerrar el objeto `StreamReader` y posteriormente eliminar el archivo, todo dentro del bloque `using` para que continúe el proceso.

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path_pagos_pos, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    contenido_pago = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    streamReader.close();
    File.Delete(path_pagos_pos);
}
```

Antes de intentar leerlo podrías usar el constructor de `FileStream` que incluye un parámetro `FileShare` para permitir que otros procesos compartan el archivo mientras lo leemos.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path_pagos_pos, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
   using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path_pagos_pos, Encoding.UTF8))
   {
      contenido_pago = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   Thread.Sleep(100);
   File.Delete(path_pagos_pos);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no me resulta, me sale el mismo error. Adjunto foto

Comment: me di cuenta que no es por eliminar, debido que está dentro de un while. Cuando estoy probando, basta con copiar el archivo en el directorio, sale ese error.